# Android Studio cannot link against -l1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have just formatted my computer and reinstalled android studio and sdk & ndk. I've created a new project but now I can't build it with c++ source because I keep getting this error:

```
.../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld: error: cannot find -l1
```

I am not event linking a library called "1". What is it for?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like latest ndk or android-studio has some sort of naming problem or I had a problem when installing it.

I was linking the android library

```
find_library(ANDROID android)
target_link_library(... ${ANDROID})
```

but it seems like ${ANDROID} was set to 1. I set it to "android" by hand and now it compiles as expected.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things the CMake toolchain file does is `set(ANDROID TRUE)` to indicate that the build is targeting Android. You can't use `ANDROID` as a variable name in your CMakeLists.txt because it's already used. Best to assume that anything prefixed with `ANDROID` is part of the implementation.